# How can Firefox scan a downloaded file for virus

Tags: antivirus, firefox

I was downloading a simple metasploit file from a CTF writeup when Firefox prevented the download: "File contains a virus or a malware".

I was working on my Linux without any antivirus preinstalled.

I wanted to know what technology is used by Firefox to scan the file. Are they using a pre-made solution (Google, ClamAV, etc.) or did they make their own technology ?

As far as a I know, firefox does not have an integrated antivirus and information about that should be public (opensource ??).

Comment: Have you googled this? ... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work#:~:text=Firefox%20contains%20built%2Din%20Phishing,designed%20to%20harm%20your%20computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official documentation which is also linked from the relevant settings in Firefox, it can be seen that it is done using Google Safe Browsing. To cite from [How does built-in Phishing and Malware Protection work?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work):

> What information is sent to Mozilla or its partners when Phishing and Malware Protection is enabled?
> ... when using Malware Protection to protect downloaded files, Firefox may communicate with Mozilla's partners to verify the safety of certain executable files. In these cases, Firefox will submit some information about the file, including the name, origin, size and a cryptographic hash of the contents, to the Google Safe Browsing service which helps Firefox determine whether or not the file should be blocked.